Fact Table Type2 History to show changes
I have 2 source tables, asset + asset attributes which I’ve modelled into a fact and 3-4 dimensions.
I created a dimension for some of the attributes to show change so if an asset is a 2 bedroom but then it changes to a 3 bedroom I can see this using SCD2. This is sort of a junk dimension as I can capture a few things that and I am happy with this.
The issue I have is the fact holds the FK for things like type and other dims, if these changes currently my fact table will just show the correct/latest key after ETL runs.
Client wants to show if a fact changed, so in 2023 it could be type A but then in 2024 it changed to type B.
This is like a slowly changing fact, can’t do snapshot so would the best thing for me to do is have fact asset and dim asset.
I am trying to keep my star schema but I don’t think I can in this scenario unless I do sort deletes on my fact table. There is only 1 update date in source as well so when something changes I need to check all the dims
Updated Example
Fact.Asset
Asset Key
Asset ID
Type Key
Tenure Key
DimTenure
TenureKey
Desc
isActive
ActiveFrom
ActiveTo
DimType
TypeKey
Desc
isActive
ActiveFrom
ActiveTo
SELECT a.AssetID,t.Desc
FROM Fact.Asset a
LEFT JOIN Dim.Tenure t ON t.TenureKey = A.TenureKey AND t.isActive = 1

This query will work and give me the current tenure for this asset, if the tenure desc renames this will also be handled with SCD2, the issue I have is if the asset changes to a different tenure my fact table will not hold the previous tenure key since when I update my fact table I clear out anything I have in staging and insert a new row with the latest keys.
What would be the best way of me handling this scenario or do I need to move these keys into a dimension.

I'm not sure I understand - are you saying that when the asset changes to a different tenure you're deleting the existing fact record? If so, why are you doing this if you want to be able to query historical facts (though deleting fact records under almost any circumstance seems to be an odd design decision)?

I don't mean actually deleting the row but I will definitely update it with the new tenure key when it changes in source so my question is should I mark the row as inactive and insert a new row for this asset with the tenure key

Yes - inserting a new row is what you need to do plus (optionally) adding one or more dates to show the effective date(s) of the fact

I have done something similar in the past but was recently told the fact should only contain the latest record and I should add anything I need to track into a dimension so would have fact.asset and dimension.asset.
I will revert back to my previous SQL where I merge and then update the existing row with an end date, set the active flag to 0 and then insert the new row.
Thanks for the help @NickW

The simplest way of doing this is probably just joining the dimension to itself. For example, if you wanted the dimension attributes on the 2023-01-01:
SELECT F.*, D2.*
FROM FACT_TABLE F
INNER JOIN DIM_TABLE D1 ON F.DIM_TABLE_SK = D1.DIM_TABLE_SK
INNER JOIN DIM_TABLE D2 ON D1.DIM_TABLE_BK = D2.DIM_TABLE_BK
WHERE D2.EFF_START_DT <= '2023-01-01' AND D2.EFF_END_DT > '2023-01-01'

SK/BK are the surrogate and business keys, respectively

Thanks but the effective dates in the dim only cover the changes of a dimension. Better example to explain might be say a fact.staff and I have a key for the dept they work in, if they move dept I want to see they previously worked for a different department. If I rename a dept this will be fine with my type 2 dimension but I won’t be able to show that emp1 dept FK was 1 and is now 2 after a promotion

If an employee moves department, rather than the department being renamed, that would be an event and therefore recorded as a new row in the relevant fact table - so you just query that table. I may still be missing something - if so please update your question with sample data and the result you are trying to achieve

I have updated my original question with a better example, hopefully this explains. I do have a solution, but I just don't think it is the best one so looking for recommendations on how I should do this rather than just making my fact work like a type 2 dimension.
